# Is it possible to show in the status which channel my discord bot is in/what song it is playing?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am currently working on a music bot and have set up an "activites" file for it. There I can set which status is displayed. But is it possible to show which channel the bot is in/what music it is playing? Even if I had to remove the file and write a few lines of code, that would not be a problem. I had already seen this with others, but never figured it out.

Comment: This would not be server specific, is that how you want it?

Comment: @Abdulaziz I just have the bot on one guild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will change this each time the music is played. using [`voice.channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=voice%20channel#discord.VoiceState.channel) you can get the channel of the author. use that to change the activity where `name` is the song name given.

```py
@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, *, name):
    # code here

    activity = discord.Activity(
        name=f"{name} @ {ctx.author.voice.channel}",
        type=discord.ActivityType.playing
        )

    await bot.change_presence(activity=activity)
```